# How to detect the end of a method chain in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Firstly and most importantly I'm trying to detect the end call of a method chain. I would also like to devise a way to detect how many methods "in" or "down" an object chain I am within my method calls in a method chain.

For instance, in the plugin I'm writing:

```
var result = $("#someDiv").myPlugin.foo().bar()._foo()._bar();
```

Say the method is currently executing in .bar() I would like to know that I'm 2 methods down the chain.

The reason I need to abstract this information in some manner is so when I reach the last method in the chain I can return a result instead of the plugin object thus breaking the chain at that point for the sake of gaining access to our data in the 'result' variable.

Comment: If I understood the problem correctly, I would rather make a `.result()` method that's called the last and which returns the value you want.

Comment: Give your last function a parameter telling it if it is the last one in the chain.

Comment: Juhana - I had thought of that but I would like to find a way for the user to return the data to a variable without needing to make an additional method call.

Comment: Ilia G - There is no way to determine in which order the methods will be called so there is no last method in the chain unfortunately.

Comment: If I used that plugin I would never want that kind of functionality, but your call.

Comment: Juhana - Considering you don't know what the plugin is, that is a lofty statement to make. The plugin allows you to work on PHP returned data directly within JavaScript, so in fact that is the main way in which you would want to use this specific plugin.

Comment: to get the number down or in, you could add a counter that incremented each time a method is called, so that if it ends in bar(), it has incremented twice and thus you are 2 down the chain

Comment: DWolf - You're right. And as it happens I just did this to figure out which method position I'm at. So this portion of the question is answered. Now I just need to create a way to find the last method of the chain. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example pulled from [your project](https://github.com/Xaxis/jqueryphp):

```
var strLenA = parseInt( P.strlen('some string').data );
var strLenB = parseInt( P.strlen('another string').data );
var totalStrLen = strLenA + strLenB;
console.log(strLenA, strLenB, totalStrLen);
```

From this I can see why our answers aren't really adequate - and why you want to get rid of `.data`. Happily, your `.data` always returns a string, anyway. So, you can use the mystical `.toString` override to have your methods still return a copy of the parent method - but also allow for them to be treated like strings.

Here's an example: [with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwDD9/)]

```
var stringMagic = function() {
    var chain = "",
        self = this;
    self.toString = function () { return chain; }; // Where the real magic happens.
    self.add = function(str) {
        chain += str + " ";
        return self;
    };
};


var magi = new stringMagic();
alert(magi.add("hello").add("world")); // Alerts, "hello world"
magi.add("and").add("thanks").add("for").add("all").add("the").add("fish");
alert(magi); // Alerts, "hello world and thanks for all the fish"
```

In your case, probably all you'd have to do is change `.data` in `P` to `.toString` and wrap it in a function.

In the future when you add support for other data types such as numbers and booleans, you can use `valueOf` in the same way you use `toString`. In fact, you should also continue to include `toString` when the return value is not a string for when they're treating that number as a string - like in `console.log` or `$.fn.text`. Here's the example above, but with numbers: http://jsfiddle.net/emqVe/1/

Comment: I really appreciate your interest and effort. You gave me some good food for thought. I went ahead and implemented data type parsing. Also I added the functionality to use specially formed JSON blocks filled with PHP "code". These blocks are executed all at once on the server and the end result is returned.

Comment: My pleasure. It was an interesting challenge so I kind of got caught up in it. Out of curiosity, why did you stick with `.data` and `.result()`/`.end()` instead of implementing something like `toString`/`valueOf`? I was considering using the `toString`/`valueOf` on a project myself but wouldn't want to if you've found some issue with it.

Comment: There is no difference with the solutions previously proposed of ending the chain with .result(). This solution works only because strings are passed as parameters and Alert applies .toString() to any non string object. In any other context, with magic = magi.add("hello").add("world"), magic is an object and out.toString() must be called to return the current text.

Comment: @widget. You're on the right track, but there is a difference. The difference is that the functionality of `.result()` is implemented in `.toString()` instead. Looking at what the OP is actually trying to accomplish in his instance (read the first part of my answer above), this is pertinent to helping resolve his actual issue. When an object is treated as a string, JavaScript automatically uses the `.ToString` method. For example, `magi.add("hello").add("world") + "s" === "hello worlds"`. If that doesn't help you in your scenario then I suggest you seek a different solution.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness. Yet another alternative is to pass a an object that will get updated as the chain progress. That would let you access the result value whenever suits you (instead of having to add it at the end of the chain).

Instead of a syntax like this:

```
var result = chainableFunction.doThis().doThat().result;
```

You would then have:

```
chainableFunction.update(variableToUpdate).doThis().doThat();
var result = variableToUpdate.result;
```

The logic is very much the same as the solution proposed by others. Which one to use probably depends on your use cases. A possible issue with having to end the chain with .result is that nothing prevents you from using it this way:

```
var chainedUp = chainableFunction.doThis().doThat();
doSomething(chainedUp.result);
... 
chainedUp.doOneMoreThing()
... 
doSomething(chainedUp.result);  // oups, .result changed!
```

With the variableToUpdate option, the result value is not affected by future function calls. Again, that could be desirable in some contexts, not in others.

Full example below

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var ChainUp = {};
(function(Class) {

  // Pure functions have no access to state and no side effects
  var Pure = {};
  Pure.isFunction = function(fn) {
     return fn && {}.toString.call(fn) === '[object Function]';
  };

  Class.instance = function() {
    var instance = {};
    var result;
    var updateRef;

    function callBack(fn) {
      // returning a clone, not a reference.
      if(updateRef) { updateRef.r = (result || []).slice(0); } 
      if(Pure.isFunction(fn)) { fn(result); }
    }

    instance.update = function(obj) {
      updateRef = obj;
      return instance;
    };

    instance.one = function(cb) {
        result = (result || []); result.push("one");
        callBack(cb);
        return instance;
      };
      instance.two = function(cb) {
        result = (result || []); result.push("two");
        callBack(cb);
        return instance;
      };
      instance.three = function(cb) {
        result = (result || []); result.push("three");
        callBack(cb);
        return instance;
      };
      instance.result = function() {
        return result;
      };
    return instance;
  };

}(ChainUp));


var result1 = {};
var chain = ChainUp.instance().update(result1);
var one = chain.one(console.log); // [ 'one' ]
console.log(one.result());        // [ 'one' ]
console.log(result1.r);           // [ 'one' ]

var oneTwo = chain.two(); 
console.log(oneTwo.result());  // [ 'one', 'two' ]
console.log(result1.r);        // [ 'one', 'two' ]

var result2 = {};
var oneTwoThree = chain.update(result2).three();
console.log(oneTwoThree.result()); // [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]
console.log(result2.r);            // [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]

console.log(result1.r);             // [ 'one', 'two' ]
```

Note. The Class and instance keywords are probably unfamiliar. That's a convention that I use when using closures instead of prototypical inheritance to construct instances from a prototype. You could replace instance with self (and self = this instead of instance = {})..

Answer (score 1):

There are no (legal or easy or nice) way to find out *inside* a method what happens with the result *outside*, after it returns with it. You should use a "chain end mark" method.

Think again, are you looking for the *last method* applied on an object, or do you want to detect something more explicite thing? Maybe you lose a possibility to apply methods on a decision (with fake silly method names):

```
obj.turnLeft().pushUp().makeBig().makeSilent;
if (colorSupport) {
  obj.paintRed();
} else {
  obj.paintStripes();
}
obj.makeShine().lastMethodCallSoObjectIsNowInFinalState();
```

Comment: I don't dwell in the world of "legal or easy or nice". ;) I am not looking for the last method applied on an object, I simple want to detect the last method to return the computed result. Perhaps by viewing my plugin you might better understand my intent: https://github.com/Xaxis/jqueryphp

Comment: Ouch, it's a brave idea! So, if I understand well, is your aim to "keeping" chain-calls on server side instead of performing separate HTTP request for each one?

Comment: If yes, your .doThis() .doThat() methods shuld only add an *command element* ("this" and "that") to the object's *command queue*, and the final *lastMethod...()* should be the one which posts that queue to server side, then it's up to the server to perform all the queued methods and return the - final - result. (If I understand your real problem.)

Comment: Don't you like the syntax: obj.phpcall("phpfunct",parm1,parm2).phpcall("anotherphpfunctwoparm").perform();  ?

Comment: Wow @Xaxis, that is brave, indeed. And might I go as far as to say it's also bad ass! So it's my understanding that you already are requiring some callback function - but it just might be defined before-hand. So the whole, "keeping a variable in `myPlugin` that gets overwritten by all the functions in your chain" thing should work great (see my updated answer) - without the need to use setTimeout since you'll be making an asynchronous call, anyway.

Comment: @Xaxis: Looking at some more of your examples (where you use `.data`) I can see that my answer isn't quite adequate. I do notice that you're using `parseInt` on `strlen`. Does `.data` always returns a string type?

Comment: @ern0 - Yes. I am in the process of developing the functionality to keep all my requests in a block and then send them to the server. Indeed with a "command queue" I will easily be able to detect the end of the stack and my problem with detecting the end method in a chain would be solved. At this point the plugin does not yet operate in that manner.

Comment: @Grinn - A callback function is only required if one wishes to return there results back into the DOM, like as the inner html of a div or something of the like. Also, at this point most of the logic in the plugin only works with synchronous calls to the server.

Comment: @Grinn - Yes a string type is always returned even if that string happens to be a JSON string in cases when an "array" is returned by PHP. It has been in the back of my mind to develop some kind of type parsing logic so users won't have to worry about parsing anything.

Comment: @Xaxis: I added a second answer that should work for you for, then. In the future you can use valueOf for other data types.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to determine if a call is the last instance in a chain *when determining the return value*, and here is why:

```
var result = $("#someDiv").myPlugin.foo().bar()._foo()._bar();
```

`foo` returns `myPlugin` on which `bar` is called which returns `myPlugin` on which `_foo` is called which returns `myPlugin` on which `_bar` is called.

So effectively, when `_foo` returns its value (`myPlugin`), it is before that value is utilized. Unless `_foo` is psychic, it can't know what will happen next.

As pointed out in your comments, your best bet is to have some "end" method, like `results()`.

Another suggestion would be to pass a handler in to `myPlugin` that gets called to set the value using `setTimeout(..., 0)`. Have a value in `myPlugin` that foo, bar, _foo, and _bar all set. Let's call it `returnValue`. Modify myPlugin to accept a method as it's only parameter. Let's call that `handler`. This method's first argument will contain the value. Inside of myPlugin, before your `return`, do:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    handler(returnValue);
}, 0);
```

Since setTimeout's function parameter will not be called until execution is finished, it will contain the last value set for `returnValue` - effectively the value set by the last call in the chain. I'd consider this the closest option to what you are trying to achieve, since the developer doesn't have to worry about which of his methods are called last.

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware that each return is the plugin itself (thus making the chaining pattern possible). The trick would be a condition that detects being the last method call and in that situation returns the result data vs. the plugin itself. I appreciate your input but I refuse to believe it isn't possible at this point.

Comment: Well I appreciate your zeal! So, you absolutely need to have it at the `return`, right? If not, there's a few more options.

Comment: Like, would you be willing to do `var result = $("#someDiv").myPlugin.foo().bar()._foo()._bar()();` or `$("#someDiv").myPlugin.foo().bar()._foo()._bar(result);` or `$("#someDiv").myPlugin(result).foo().bar()._foo()._bar();`?

Comment: What i'm currently doing is just: `$("#someDiv").myPlugin.foo().bar()._foo().someMethod().data` ... That is just setting a property to hold the return data which works just fine. It's just I would really prefer to not need to do that.

Comment: Well, I included an explanation of how to do `$("#someDiv").myPlugin(result).foo().bar()._foo()._bar();` since it most closely resembles what you're trying to attempt. The developer still won't need to keep track of which method is called last in the chain, but I know this isn't exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Yeah I have considered passing a flag as a parameter to the plugin like requiring the user to pass the name of the last method in the chain or maybe the number of methods in the chain or any way that would allow me to set a condition to return the data after the last method call but so far I feel that the most elegant way is to have them just add the `.data` property to the end of the chain to return the result to a variable. ... Still though, as you know, I would like to get rid of the need for that requirement too. :-\

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way, however, you can add a parameter to the method meant to be chained as you want. And determine if the current call is the latest by setting it to `true`, as in:

```
var AlertText = {
  text: "",
  chainEntry: function(textToAdd, isTheLastOne) {
    this.text += textToAdd;
    // Perform only if this is told to be the last call in the chain:
    if (isTheLastOne) {
      alert(this.text);
      this.text = "";
    }
    //
    return this;
  }
};

AlertText
  .chainEntry("Hi, ")
  .chainEntry("how ")
  .chainEntry("are ")
  .chainEntry("you?", true); // alert("Hi, how are you?");
```